# upgrade records in Moodle database

Tags: sql-server, database, moodle, corruption

i have an issue, which seems it is a database fault, all of a sudden some users are not able to login, it gives them a 500 internal server error. After turning the debugging in Moodle and in PHP as well i cannot see any others error just the internal one.

When i try to modify an account through Moodle (change the name or something) it does not let me keeping loading forever and gives me the internal error again. i also tried changing data straight from the database resulting in crushing of the table and a timeout error in the end.

Is the database corrupted? i am using MS SQL by the way, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "crushing of the table"? What does this mean? A 500 internal error means nothing on it's own; we need to know the route cause behind that,

Comment: the table crushes, not responding for some seconds, then i get a timeout error, i know that the 500 internal error means nothing but i can't get it to show more, display of errors in php.ini file and debugging in config file is on

Comment: So, if the table is unresponsive, I **assume** others are? If sounds, sounds like table locking.

Comment: dear larnu, thank you so much for directing me to the correct location, indeed tables are locking when i try to update a profile from within moodle, it seems it's a php issue

Comment: is there a way to track down exactly what is causing the issue?

Comment: How are you connecting PHP to MSSQL? Using the SQLSRV driver or FreeTDS - or something else?